# How to use 2 different AWS credential providers to access S3 and Glue catalog separately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue, credential-providers

I have a use case where I want to write data to S3 based data lake using Glue catalog.

I am going to use EMR which is configured to use Glue catalog as the meta store for Spark SQL. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

I have got that bit working. I can write simple SQL scripts to load data to S3 and update glue catalog at the same time.

I want to use 2 different credentials to access S3 and for Glue. With `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider` property, I would be able provide Spark with a custom AWS credential for S3 access.

Is there a similar property in Spark to configure a separate credential provider for Glue catalog access?

Answer (score 2):

Update: I found the place where the GlueMetastoreFactory creates Glue client: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore/blob/4b31eaf86fa15362c0b0b82b9c0942052c45df7c/aws-glue-datacatalog-client-common/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/glue/catalog/metastore/AWSGlueClientFactory.java#L48-L49

It uses `aws.catalog.credentials.provider.factory.class` property to load the custom credential class for Glue: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore/blob/branch-3.4.0/aws-glue-datacatalog-client-common/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/glue/catalog/util/AWSGlueConfig.java#L11-L12

I will try this some more and update this answer with details.

Comment: This is promising and I am trying to do something similar so that we can unit test our PySpark jobs. 
Currently I'm using `moto[server]` to mock the S3 calls when reading & writing S3.  This is working following similar concept to that in https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-jobs-unit-testing/blob/main/tests/test_sample.py and repointing `fs.s3.endpoint` to moto.
I am trying to get Spark catalogue related calls redirected to moto server eg `DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable()` and `spark.sql('CREATE DATABASE')`, so our code can be unit tested without connecting to the real AWS Glue catalogue.